# Subcategories with Ajax and Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have select box with categories and I want to display subcategories in another select box using ajax an CodeIgniter.

This is part of my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tip_category').change(function(){
        msg = 'category_id='+$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '<?php echo base_url().'admin/tips/ajax_subcategory';?>',
                data : msg


    });
    });    
});

</script>

Category:<br/>
<select name="tip_category" id="tip_category">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['id'] ?>"><?php echo $category['name'] ?>
        </option>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select><br/>

Subcategory:<br/>
<select name="tip_subcategory"
    <?php if(isset($subcategories)): ?>
        <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $subcategory['id'] ?>"><?php echo $subcategory['name'] ?>
            </option>    
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select><br/>
```

This is part of my controller:

```
public function ajax_subcategory() {
    $this->load->model('tips_model');
    $data['subcategories'] = $this->tips_model->get_subcategories($this->input->post('category_id'));     
}
```

My problem is that i dont know how to send data ($data['subcategories']) back to view and display subcategories. Thx for help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing the return (in whatever format you need):

> return $data;

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your controller to:

```
public function ajax_subcategory() {
    $this->load->model('tips_model');
    $data['subcategories'] = $this->tips_model->get_subcategories($this->input->post('category_id'));
    return $this->output->set_output($data);     
}
```